Proof that each natural number has a unique successor
I've proven that every positive natural number has a unique predecessor using Peano's axioms. But now, I was wondering how I could prove that every natural number has a unique successor using the same axiomatic system. Of course, by Peano's axioms, if $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then $\sigma(n)\in\mathbb{N}$. But how do I show that this natural number is unique?

$\sigma$ is supposed to be a function.

@ameg so is the unique successor fact implicitly assumed since $\sigma$ is a function?

Right. It's an unstated axiom.

Another unstated axiom is the existence if $0$. It's quite consistent with the other axioms for there to exist no natural numbers at all.

MJD, in what sense are these axioms "unstated"? Normally, the existance of 0 (or 1) is the first axiom. Then there is an set of axioms about a successor function that should exist and have such-and-such properties.

Sometimes they are stated explicitly, sometimes they aren't. If the version OP had seen had stated them explicitly, they wouldn't ve asking the question.

@MJD I'm actually following Tao's analysis, which does have an axiom that "0 is a natural number". The reason I asked this question was because Tao introduced Peano's axioms before defining functions. So, the increment of n would be denoted as n++. However Tao doesn't assume that there is a unique successor. Hence, it feels as though we'd need to further assume the unique successor proposition in such an axiomatic system.

The OP should have stated the axioms to use...

For examples of both styles of formulating the Peano axioms, see (for example) G. Boolos, “Frege's Theorem and the Peano Postulates”, Bulletin of Symbolic Logic, vol 1 #3 (Sep 1995).  A three-axiom version where the existence of 0 is implicit appears on page 318.

The successor function, $\sigma(n)$, defines the successor of  a number $n$. You don't need to prove that it's unique - it's a function - i.e., for any $n$ this function gives just one value (usually called $n+1$) which will be defined as the successor. The only successor.
After understanding that, you might wander now whether is is possible that two different numbers $m$ and $n$  have the same successor $k$. This is not possible because of the predecessor uniqueness that you said you proved: both $m$ and $n$ are predecessors of $k$ so if the predecessor is unique, they must be equal.

As others have pointed out, this trivially follows from the fact that the successor function is just that: a function.
But if it helps, here is a formal proof:

